# Binding HashMap to ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, hashmap

Does anybody have an example of how to binding the keys of a HashMap to a ComboBox so that the changes in the HashMap are instantly reflected to the ComboBox?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Solution thanks to "Hovercraft Full Of Eels":

```
private Map<String, String> format = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

    public class ToComboBoxModel<String> extends AbstractListModel<String> implements MutableComboBoxModel<String> {

        private String selectedItem;

        @Override
        public Object getSelectedItem() {
            return selectedItem;
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (java.lang.String str : format.keySet()){
                if (anItem.equals(str))
                {
                    selectedItem=(String) str;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getElementAt(int index) {         
            List<Entry<String,String>> randAccess = new ArrayList<Entry<String,String>>((Collection<? extends Entry<String, String>>) format.entrySet());

            return randAccess.get(index).getKey();
        }

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return format.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeElement(Object obj) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void removeElementAt(int index) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void addElement(String item) {


        }

        @Override
        public void insertElementAt(String item, int index) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a class that implements the `MutableComboBoxModel<T>` interface and have it use a `TreeMap<T>` or some other child of `SortedMap<T>` as its data nucleus. I don't think that you'd want to use a `HashMap` since the model of a JComboBox needs to be ordered and a HashMap is not ordered.

The class should also extend the [`AbstractListModel<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html) in order to gain the ListModel's functionality automatically saving you from having to maintain your own EventListenerList and giving you two of the bottom four methods in my list above for free, as well as some `fireXXX(...)` data change notification methods.

What you must do is create the necessary methods dictated by the `MutableComboBoxModel<T>`'s interface's [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/MutableComboBoxModel.html). This would only mean implementing 12 methods,

- 4 of `MutableComboBoxModel<E>`,

  - `void addElement(E item)`
  - `void insertElementAt(E item, int index)`
  - `void removeElement(E obj)`
  - `void removeElementAt(int index)`
- 2 of `ComboBoxModel<E>`,

  - `E getSelectedItem()`
  - `void setSelectedItem(E item)`
- and 4 of `ListModel<E>`,

  - `void addListDataListener(ListDataListener listener)` no need to write -- part of AbstractListModel
  - `E getElementAt(int index)`
  - `int getSize()`
  - `void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener listener)` no need to write -- part of AbstractListModel

This should be do-able, I should think.

Edit: on looking this over some more, I'm having an issue with `insertElementAt(...)`. Since I've advocated a SortedMap as the model's nucleus, you can't add an element arbitrarily into the a position in the Map since it is sorted by its "natural" order. This works best with using an ArrayList, Vector or other similar collection as the model's data nucleus.

**Edit 2**: Much better to use a **LinkedHashMap** as per Omid's suggestion.

Comment: ok thanks but how do I actually go about to getting the items into the listbox?

Comment: agreed with MutableComboBoxModel

Comment: @Omid: You're welcome. I think that you're asking how to add items to the model and have it show up in the JComboBox? If so, then your `addElement(...)` method would add data to the model's inner map and then call the `fireXXX(...)` method to notify the listening JCOmboBox. If this is not your question, then can you please clarify your question?

Comment: yeah I'm adding the item using addElement, but unable to call the "firexxx(...)". Is it "fireIntervalAdded" that needs to be called?

Comment: @Omid: yes, that is the method that needs to be called if you're adding elements. Note that you will need to calculate the interval, and since you're not using an ArrayList, you will probably need to iterate through the Map's keys to find out the values of the involved indices.

Comment: I'm using "List<Entry<String,String>> randAccess = new ArrayList<Entry<String,String>>((Collection<? extends Entry<String, String>>) format.entrySet());". Then "return randAccess.get(index).getKey();" under "getElementAt".

Comment: @Omid: for more help, you'll probably want to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I'm using a LinkedHashMap now which is much better. I don't need sorted :)

Comment: @Omid: that is a very wise choice, and if you don't mind I will put it in my answer. 1+ to you.